# PHP > How to skip an element while using json_encode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to send data to the client side in JSON format.

So far, it worked just fine with json_encode as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT `card`.`CardID`,`card`.`Text`,... WHERE (`card`.`CardID`= :ItemId)";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':ItemId', $itemid);   
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    $posts[]=$row;
}

...
...

$res["rows"] = $posts;
$res["maptel"] = $maptelindicator;

echo json_encode($res,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

But now I have a problem. I have a new field (Videofiles) in the DB that is already JSON formatted- stored as the ouput of a SDK function. If I encode this JSON encoded field once more, I get data which is unreadable on the client side..

How can I json_encode all the other data, but skip this specific field, Videofiles?

Here is the output of a sample data structure using print_r:

```
Array
(
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Name] => Company13
                    [CID] => 26
                    [CardID] => 26-000002
                    [Text] => Kleopatra Deluxe Hotel reservations
                    [ImageLink] => 
                    [VideoFiles] => [{"quality":"mobile","type":"video/mp4","width":480,"height":270....}]
                    [ClickDate] => 2015-11-03
                )

        )

    [maptel] => 0
)
```

Thanks...

Comment: Rather than decoding all but Videofiles it may be easier to iterate over your result and decode Videofiles, then encode the entire array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `json_decode` to decode the already encoded field and then add the result in the `$res` array.

Comment: Thanks.. I will look for ways to add the fields to the $posts variable one by one and run json_decode before adding this specific field.

Comment: For anyone who is interested, following code did the trick: 
  
    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
      $posts[]['CardID']=$row["CardID"];
      $posts[0]['Text']=$row["Text"];
      $posts[0]['VideoFiles']=json_decode($row["VideoFiles"]);

Answer (score 0):

> Best way to do it delete this section in SQL!

But if you want to delete in php **it will have a cost for you** and you can use unset for this situation;

```
foreach ($posts as $post){
    unset($posts['VideoFiles']);
}

$res["rows"] = $posts;
$res["maptel"] = $maptelindicator;

echo json_encode($res,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: In the end, I will need to add this to the json_encoded data structure. I still need to send it accross.. Thanks anyway.